# Error "Object required" while well declared

Tags: excel, vba

Since the beginning of the day, I've been struggling with an error "424" telling me .

The thing is I know I have to put it in a Dim X As XXX and even with this, it doesn't work. And it's neither a problem of bad type.

Here you can see my exact code (you don't need to read everything) :

```
Sub Macro12()

Dim wsDashboard As Worksheet
Dim wsDeliverables As Worksheet
Dim wsQuarters As Worksheet
Dim wsChallenges As Worksheet
Dim wsMetachallenges As Worksheet
Dim rMetachallenges As Range
Dim rMetachallengesID As Range
Dim rMetachallengesName As Range
Dim rChallenges As Range
Dim rChallengesID As Range
Dim rChallengesName As Range
Dim rQuarters As Range
Dim rQuartersID As Range
Dim rQuartersName As Range
Dim rDeliverables As Range
Dim rTitles As Range
Dim rFoundQuarter As Range
Dim rFoundChallenge As Range
Dim rFoundMetachallenge As Range
Dim rrHierarchicalLevels As Range
Dim rdHierarchicalLevels As Range
Dim rqHierarchicalLevels As Range
Dim rcHierarchicalLevels As Range
Dim rdDebuts As Range
Dim rqDebuts As Range
Dim rcDebuts As Range
Dim rrDebuts As Range
Dim rdFins As Range
Dim rqFins As Range
Dim rcFins As Range
Dim rrFins As Range
Dim rcTypes As Range
Dim rrTypes As Range
Dim rcSegments As Range
Dim rrSegments As Range
Dim rcStrategicalImportances As Range
Dim rrStrategicalImportances As Range
Dim rcKTDLeads As Range
Dim rrKTDLeads As Range
Dim rcOtherKTDLeads As Range
Dim rrOtherKTDLeads As Range
Dim rcTRTLeads As Range
Dim rrTRTLeads As Range
Dim rcOtherTRTLeads As Range
Dim rrOtherTRTLeads As Range
Dim rdStarts As Range
Dim rcStarts As Range
Dim rqStarts As Range
Dim rrStarts As Range
Dim rdEnds As Range
Dim rqEnds As Range
Dim rcEnds As Range
Dim rrEnds As Range
Dim rdUpdatedEnds As Range
Dim rqUpdatedEnds As Range
Dim rcUpdatedEnds As Range
Dim rrUpdatedEnds As Range
Dim rdStatus As Range
Dim rqStatus As Range
Dim rcStatus As Range
Dim rrStatus As Range
Dim rdAdvancements As Range
Dim rqAdvancements As Range
Dim rcAdvancements As Range
Dim rrAdvancements As Range
Dim lTotalDeliverables As Long
Dim lQuarter As Long
Dim lChallenge As Long
Dim lMetachallenge As Long
Dim lNextQuarter As Long
Dim lNextChallenge As Long
Dim lNextMetachallenge As Long
Dim lAddedlines As Long
Dim lTest As Long


Set wsDashboard = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Dashboard") 'variable faisant référence à la spreadsheet "MENU"
Set wsDeliverables = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("deliverables") 'variable faisant référence à la spreadsheet "TRT RTI Challenges"
Set wsQuarters = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("quarters")
Set wsChallenges = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("challenges")
Set wsMetachallenges = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("metachallenges")
Set rMetachallenges = Range("t_deliverables").ListObject.ListColumns("id_metachallenge").DataBodyRange
Set rMetachallengesID = Range("t_metachallenges").ListObject.ListColumns("id").DataBodyRange
Set rMetachallengesName = Range("t_metachallenges").ListObject.ListColumns("Metachallenges").DataBodyRange
Set rChallenges = Range("t_deliverables").ListObject.ListColumns("id_challenge").DataBodyRange 'variable faisant référence à la colonne "Associated_challenge" du tableau "t_deliverables" de la spreadsheet "TRT RTI Challenges"
Set rChallengesID = Range("t_challenges").ListObject.ListColumns("id").DataBodyRange
Set rChallengesName = Range("t_challenges").ListObject.ListColumns("Challenges").DataBodyRange
Set rQuarters = Range("t_deliverables").ListObject.ListColumns("id_quarter").DataBodyRange 'variable faisant référence à la colonne "Associated_quarter" du tableau "t_deliverables" de la spreadsheet "TRT RTI Challenges"
Set rQuartersID = Range("t_quarters").ListObject.ListColumns("id").DataBodyRange
Set rQuartersName = Range("t_quarters").ListObject.ListColumns("Quarters").DataBodyRange
Set rDeliverables = Range("t_deliverables").ListObject.ListColumns("RTI Challenge Title").DataBodyRange 'variable faisant référence à la colonne "RTI Challenge Title" du tableau "t_deliverables" de la spreadsheet "TRT RTI Challenges"
Set rTitles = Range("t_dashboard").ListObject.ListColumns("RTI Challenges").DataBodyRange
Set rrHierarchicalLevels = Range("t_dashboard").ListObject.ListColumns("Hierarchical Level").DataBodyRange
Set rdHierarchicalLevels = Range("t_deliverables").ListObject.ListColumns("Hierarchical Level").DataBodyRange
Set rcHierarchicalLevels = Range("t_challenges").ListObject.ListColumns("Hierarchical Level").DataBodyRange
Set rqHierarchicalLevels = Range("t_quarters").ListObject.ListColumns("Hierarchical Level").DataBodyRange
Set rdDebuts = Range("t_deliverables").ListObject.ListColumns("Début").DataBodyRange
Set rqDebuts = Range("t_quarters").ListObject.ListColumns("Début").DataBodyRange
Set rcDebuts = Range("t_challenges").ListObject.ListColumns("Début").DataBodyRange
Set rrDebuts = Range("t_dashboard").ListObject.ListColumns("Début").DataBodyRange
Set rdFins = Range("t_deliverables").ListObject.ListColumns("Fin").DataBodyRange
Set rqFins = Range("t_quarters").ListObject.ListColumns("Fin").DataBodyRange
Set rcFins = Range("t_challenges").ListObject.ListColumns("Fin").DataBodyRange
Set rrFins = Range("t_dashboard").ListObject.ListColumns("Fin").DataBodyRange
Set rrTypes = Range("t_dashboard").ListObject.ListColumns("Type").DataBodyRange
Set rcSegments = Range("t_challenges").ListObject.ListColumns("SEGMENT PCC").DataBodyRange
Set rrSegments = Range("t_dashboard").ListObject.ListColumns("SEGMENT PCC").DataBodyRange
Set rcStrategicalImportances = Range("t_challenges").ListObject.ListColumns("Strategical Importance").DataBodyRange
Set rrStrategicalImportances = Range("t_dashboard").ListObject.ListColumns("Strategical Importance").DataBodyRange
Set rcKTDLeads = Range("t_challenges").ListObject.ListColumns("KTD Lead").DataBodyRange
Set rrKTDLeads = Range("t_dashboard").ListObject.ListColumns("KTD Lead").DataBodyRange
Set rcOtherKTDLeads = Range("t_challenges").ListObject.ListColumns("Other KTD involved").DataBodyRange
Set rrOtherKTDLeads = Range("t_dashboard").ListObject.ListColumns("Other KTD involved").DataBodyRange
Set rcTRTLeads = Range("t_challenges").ListObject.ListColumns("TRT Lead").DataBodyRange
Set rrTRTLeads = Range("t_dashboard").ListObject.ListColumns("TRT Lead").DataBodyRange
Set rcOtherTRTLeads = Range("t_challenges").ListObject.ListColumns("Other TRT / Team involved").DataBodyRange
Set rrOtherTRTLeads = Range("t_dashboard").ListObject.ListColumns("Other TRT / Team involved").DataBodyRange
Set rdStarts = Range("t_deliverables").ListObject.ListColumns("Start (T0)").DataBodyRange
Set rcStarts = Range("t_challenges").ListObject.ListColumns("Start (T0)").DataBodyRange
Set rqStarts = Range("t_quarters").ListObject.ListColumns("Start (T0)").DataBodyRange
Set rrStarts = Range("t_dashboard").ListObject.ListColumns("Start (T0)").DataBodyRange
Set rdEnds = Range("t_deliverables").ListObject.ListColumns("End date").DataBodyRange
Set rcEnds = Range("t_challenges").ListObject.ListColumns("End date").DataBodyRange
Set rqEnds = Range("t_quarters").ListObject.ListColumns("End date").DataBodyRange
Set rrEnds = Range("t_dashboard").ListObject.ListColumns("End date").DataBodyRange
Set rdUpdatedEnds = Range("t_deliverables").ListObject.ListColumns("Updated End date").DataBodyRange
Set rcUpdatedEnds = Range("t_challenges").ListObject.ListColumns("Updated End date").DataBodyRange
Set rqUpdatedEnds = Range("t_quarters").ListObject.ListColumns("Updated End date").DataBodyRange
Set rrUpdatedEnds = Range("t_dashboard").ListObject.ListColumns("Updated End date").DataBodyRange
Set rdStatus = Range("t_deliverables").ListObject.ListColumns("Status").DataBodyRange
Set rqStatus = Range("t_quarters").ListObject.ListColumns("Status").DataBodyRange
Set rcStatus = Range("t_challenges").ListObject.ListColumns("Status").DataBodyRange
Set rrStatus = Range("t_dashboard").ListObject.ListColumns("Status").DataBodyRange
Set rdAdvancements = Range("t_deliverables").ListObject.ListColumns("Deliverable Avancement").DataBodyRange
Set rqAdvancements = Range("t_quarters").ListObject.ListColumns("Deliverable Avancement").DataBodyRange
Set rcAdvancements = Range("t_challenges").ListObject.ListColumns("Deliverable Avancement").DataBodyRange
Set rrAdvancements = Range("t_dashboard").ListObject.ListColumns("Deliverable Avancement").DataBodyRange

'Set rSegment = Range("t_deliverables").ListObject.ListColumns("SEGMENT PCC").DataBodyRange 'variable faisant référence à la colonne "SEGMENT PCC" du tableau "t_deliverables" de la spreadsheet "TRT RTI Challenges"
'Set rStart = Range("t_deliverables").ListObject.ListColumns("Start (T0)").DataBodyRange 'variable faisant référence à la colonne "Start (T0)" du tableau "t_deliverables" de la spreadsheet "TRT RTI Challenges"
'Set rEnd = Range("t_deliverables").ListObject.ListColumns("End date").DataBodyRange 'variable faisant référence à la colonne "End date" du tableau "t_deliverables" de la spreadsheet "TRT RTI Challenges"
'Set rFeedbackDone = Range("t_deliverables").ListObject.ListColumns("Feedback given to TRT Leader ?").DataBodyRange 'variable faisant référence à la colonne "Feedback given to TRT Leader ?" du tableau "t_deliverables" de la spreadsheet "TRT RTI Challenges"
'Set rHierarchicalLevel = Range("t_deliverables").ListObject.ListColumns("Hierarchical Level").DataBodyRange 'variable faisant référence à la colonne "Hierarchical Level" du tableau "t_deliverables" de la spreadsheet "TRT RTI Challenges"
'Set rStatus = Range("t_deliverables").ListObject.ListColumns("Status").DataBodyRange
'Set rNumsChall = Range("t_deliverables").ListObject.ListColumns("N° Chall.").DataBodyRange
'Set rInsertedQuarters = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("quarters").Range("R:R")

wsDashboard.Select
Cells.Select
Selection.ClearFormats
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("t_dashboard").TableStyle = ""

Range("t_dashboard").ListObject.DataBodyRange.Delete

lTotalDeliverables = rDeliverables.Cells.Count

'Tri la spreadsheet "deliverables"
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("deliverables").ListObjects("t_deliverables").Sort. _
    SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("deliverables").ListObjects("t_deliverables").Sort. _
    SortFields.Add Key:=Range("t_deliverables[id_metachallenge]"), SortOn:= _
    xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("deliverables").ListObjects("t_deliverables").Sort. _
    SortFields.Add Key:=Range("t_deliverables[id_challenge]"), SortOn:= _
    xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("deliverables").ListObjects("t_deliverables").Sort. _
    SortFields.Add Key:=Range("t_deliverables[id_quarter]"), SortOn:= _
    xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("deliverables").ListObjects("t_deliverables").Sort. _
    SortFields.Add Key:=Range("t_deliverables[id_deliverable]"), SortOn:= _
    xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("deliverables").ListObjects("t_deliverables"). _
    Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

lQuarter = 0
lChallenge = 0
lMetachallenge = 0

lAddedlines = 0

'For i = 2 To lTotalDeliverables + 1
For i = 2 To 10
    lNextQuarter = wsDeliverables.Cells(i, rQuarters.Column).Value
    lNextChallenge = wsDeliverables.Cells(i, rChallenges.Column).Value
    lNextMetachallenge = wsDeliverables.Cells(i, rMetachallenges.Column).Value
    If lNextMetachallenge <> lMetachallenge Then
        wsDashboard.Select
        wsDashboard.Cells(1, 1).Select
        Selection.ListObject.ListRows.Add AlwaysInsert:=True

        Set rFoundMetachallenge = rMetachallengesID.Find(lNextMetachallenge, rMetachallengesID.Cells(rMetachallengesID.Cells.Count), xlValues, xlWhole, , xlNext, False)

        wsMetachallenges.Select
        wsMetachallenges.Cells(rFoundMetachallenge.Row, rMetachallengesName.Column).Select
        Selection.Copy
        wsDashboard.Select
        lTest = rTitles.Column
        'Cells(i + lAddedlines, rTitles.Column).Select

    End If
Next i
```

At the line "lTest = rTitles.Column" I get the error and I really really don't understand the reason why. The only thing I know is that rTitles.Column is not understood.

I wrote this line in order to understand why "'Cells(i + lAddedlines, rTitles.Column).Select" wasn't working. Indeed, on this line, I get the same error and it seems as weel to come from rTitles.

Thanks to anyone that could help me. Really !

Arthur :)

Comment: Woah. First, it's best to [avoid using `.Select`/`.Activate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba). Second, are you sure you need all those variables? That looks like it'll be really tricky to maintain...What does the messagebox say if you put `msgbox rTitles.Address` right before the `lTest = ...` line?

Comment: `Set rTitles = Range("t_dashboard").ListObject.ListColumns("RTI Challenges").DataBodyRange` Are you sure this is like this? If `t_dashboard` is the name of a worksheet, then it should be something like `Set rTitles = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("t_dashboard").ListObjects("NameofyourListObject").ListColumns("RTI Challenges").DataBodyRange`

Comment: t_dashboard is a named range? but at one point you delete "Range("t_dashboard").ListObject.DataBodyRange.Delete"

Comment: t_dashboard is a table in my worksheet "Dashboard"

Comment: MsgBox rTitles.Address gives me an error as well

Comment: I checked : Range.Column is supposed to give me the number of the column related to rTitles, so a Long (and lTest is a Long as well)

Comment: if `rTitles.Address` give an error it suggest there is no `"RTI Challenges"` or a typo in the name.

Comment: Moreover, i deleted the rest of the code but see: wsDashboard.Select Cells(i + lAddedlines, rrFins.Column).Select  works really fine for example

Comment: There is no typo in the name and I checked every variables' name hundred times. It's like there is a bug...

Comment: What does `msgbox Range("t_dashboard").Address` show? That is a named range, set up correctly yeah?

Comment: `Option Explicit`, every time. Every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `rTitles.Address` gives an error, `rTitles` is not set to a range. 
I believe that this is caused by the line

`Range("t_dashboard").ListObject.DataBodyRange.Delete`.

You first set the range, but you delete it afterwards. That's why it doesn't exist anymore later on.

Comment: You got it ! Thanks a lot :D